# An Example for the Partition of Unity for a Circle

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, paracompactness

I am trying to wrap my head around on what partition of unity means and trying to understand some examples of it. I have an engineering background so most of the abstract discussions are a little hard for me to grasp without a clear explanation and examples. Also I have no formal education on topology, however I really want to self study this subject. The problem is due to a misunderstanding of some concepts so a clear explanation is appreciated.

On [this page](https://planetmath.org/partitionofunity) an example is given for a partition of unity on a circle $S^1$ as $\{sin^2(\theta/2),cos^2(\theta/2)\}$ subordinate to the covering $\{(0,2\pi),(-\pi,\pi)\}$.

The set of functions $\{sin^2(\theta/2),cos^2(\theta/2)\}$ add up to 1, so that condition is satisfied. However, if we denote the topological space by $X$ and the functions by $\epsilon_i$, according to the definition:

> A partition of unity is subordinate to an open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $X$
> if each $\epsilon_i$ is zero on the complement of $U_i$.

If we parameterize $S^1$ by an angle in the range $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$, then it means that the function $\epsilon_1 = sin^2(\theta/2)$ must be zero on the complement of $U_1 = (0,2\pi)$. The comlpement is $U_1^c = 0$, hence $\epsilon_1$ vanishes on $U_1^c$. Also, the function $\epsilon_2 = cos^2(\theta/2)$ must be zero on the complement of $U_2 = (-\pi,\pi)$. First of all, what is the complement of $U_2$ in this context? Is it $U_2^c = [\pi,2\pi)$?! If it is, then there are plenty of points on $U_2^c$ that yield non-zero values for $\epsilon_2$! What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There's a little abuse of notation: $U_i$ should be defined as an open subset of your manifold, ie as an open subset of $S^1$. So $U_1 = \{e^{ix},\, 0 < x < 2\pi\}$ and a similar expression for $U_2$.

Comment: Are $U_1$ and $U_2$ functions? I thought that they are some intervals on the real line! But my main question is, what is the complement of $U_1$ and how the function $sin^2(\theta/2)$ is zero on this complement? Please give a step by step explanation if you can. I am not good at these stuff!

Comment: No, they're not functions! They're subsets *of the circle*. So the complement of $U_1$ is $e^{i0}= 1$ and the corresponding $\theta$ is zero (mod $2\pi$) so that the function $\sin^2{\theta/2}$ is $\sin^2{0/2}=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  If the space under investigation is $S^1: e^{i\theta}|, 0 \leq \theta <2\pi$, then as you said, the complement of $U_1=(0,2\pi)$ is 0. Hence the function $\epsilon_1$ is zero on the complement. What is the complement of $U_2 = (-\pi,\pi)$? Is it $U_2^c = [\pi,2\pi)$? Because the function $\epsilon_2$ must be zero on $U_2^c $ and I don't see how it does happen.

Comment: It should be noted that the definition of "subordinate to a cover" given in the linked PlanetMath page (each $\varepsilon_i$ is zero on the complement of $U_i$) is highly nonstandard. The standard definition is the one given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity): the [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) of $\varepsilon_i$ is contained in $U_i$. With this definition, the partition of unity for the circle given in the example is _not_ subordinate to the given cover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The covering of $S^1$ that is given is misleading IMO.

The mean by $U_1 = (0,2\pi)$ the open set $U_1:= \{e^{ix}: x \in (0,2\pi)\}$, really. So they're referring to the unique angle in $[0,2\pi)$ that defines the point on $S^1$. Similarly for $U_2$.

If we look at $\sin^2(\frac\theta 2)$ (the value for $e^{i\theta} \in S^1$), we indeed see that is is $0$ iff $\frac\theta 2$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$, so iff $\theta$ is an integer multiple of $2\pi$, and so only $0$ when $\theta \notin U_1$ (recall that $\theta$ is chosen in $[0,2\pi)$ (main angle)).

Now reason similarly for $f(e^{i \theta})=\cos^2(\frac \theta 2)$: $0$ only for $\frac \theta 2$ of the form $\frac \pi 2 + k\pi, k \in \Bbb Z$ so $\theta$ of the form $\pi + k 2 \pi, k \in \Bbb Z$ and no such value lies in $U_2$.

Note that $U_2$ is $S^1$ minus the single point where the function is $0$ (i.e. $(-1,0)$) too, just like $U_1$ is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In your arguments you state that, for example, for $sin^2(\theta/2)$ to be zero we must have $\theta=2\pi k$ and that condition is not satisfied for $\theta \in U_1$. However, what I don't understand is the next step that you take. The fact that $\theta=2\pi k$ is satisfied for SOME points $\theta \notin U_1$ doesn't mean that for ALL points $\theta \notin U_1$ we must have $sin^2(\theta/2)=0$. Which is a part of the definition. Is that correct?

Comment: So basically the statement given in https://planetmath.org/partitionofunity is wrong. Is that correct?

Comment: @AliPedram no it is correct according to the definition when you understand what the open sets actually are.

Comment: Also what do you mean by "There the support is not contained in $U_2$"? The support is the set of all points that give non-zero output for a function. There are plenty of points in $U_2 = (-\pi,\pi)$ which give $cos^2(\theta/2) \neq 0$. What did you exactly mean?

Comment: @AliPedram some definitions of partition of unity require that the support of $f$ is contained in  the open set. The support of a function $f$ equals $\overline{\{x\mid f(x) \neq0\}}$. For both these functions the support is $S^1$. So try they do not obey the stricter definition.

Comment: What is the complement of $U_2 = (-\pi,\pi)$?

Comment: @AliPedram all of the circle except $e^{i\pi}=(-1,0)$

Comment: Then how does $cos^2(\theta/2)=0$ for all points on the circle except the one that you have mentioned?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130394/discussion-between-henno-brandsma-and-ali-pedram).